# Convert base64 data url to image file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, base64

I have base64 data URL in my angularJs controller, and I need an image file from that, so that I could send it to server as multi-part data through ajax?

I'm looking for something like file writer in angularjs.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 22):

you can generate blob from base64 data.

```
var imageBase64 = "image base64 data";
var blob = new Blob([imageBase64], {type: 'image/png'});
```

From this blob, you can generate file object.

```
var file = new File([blob], 'imageFileName.png');
```

You can use this file object and post it to server using multipart data.

Comment: Any time :) glad i helped :)

Comment: Althogh when I save the image, it says not a png file and won't let me view it. Can you tell why?

Comment: The blob file is going with content type as application/octet-stream, instead of image/png, to the server(python django), which is why I'm guessing it's not able to save it as image file. I'm not sure how to make a plunkr of this.

Comment: you can pass blob type in blob constructor. check my updated answer